# VT-X/AMD-v not enabled in Ubuntu already running in Virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization

I have the following scenario. 
I am running a Ubuntu 14 LTS in a Virtualbox on a Windows 10 system.

Within this ubuntu I would like to install a Virtualbox where I need to run a custom docker ISO image.

Now, the problem seems to be the fact that the Virtualbox within the Ubuntu doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled.

VT-X/AMD-v is enabled on my system, all works well. How can I enable it within the second virtualbox?

Windows10-> VirtualBox(VT-X/AMD-v OK)->Ubuntu->Virtualbox(VT-X/AMD-v missing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested virtualization is [not supported by VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032). If nested virtualization is important for you, I suggest you try other virtualization applications that support it (e.g. KVM or VMware ESXi / VM player).

Comment: Thanks! Very useful information! Digged around for hours...