# docker : When creating a machine, VT-X/AMD is enabled yet

Tags: docker, virtualbox, virtualization, docker-compose

I'm going through this tutorial

[Dockerizing Flask With Compose and Machine - From Localhost to the Cloud](https://realpython.com/blog/python/dockerizing-flask-with-compose-and-machine-from-localhost-to-the-cloud/)

When trying to create a virtualbox with the command below

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox dev;
```

I have the following error

> Error creating machine : Error in driver during machine creation. This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory

(Addendum: I'm running an ubuntu image on a virtual box. The physical host is a windows machine. The VT `VT-X/AMD` is enabled both , in the bios and in the virtualbox.)

Reading here and there, it seems to be a normal behavior because I'm trying to create a virtualbox within a virtualbox -> [Click here for the explanation](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2256)

What command should I use instead of `docker-machine` ?

Any insights are more than welcomed ...

**Update**: I've asked 3 additional questions to @VonC after his initial answer. Please find the questions below , *in italic*

*1) How should I make the virtualbox and the docker config see that new "virtualbox"?*

*2) Will the ubuntu box, be able to do the docker-compose and build the container on that host?*

*3) If I'm pulling an image like debian, how can I use it as a machine and build an container on top of it?*

Comment: " I'm running ubuntu box on a virtual box" are you in a VM already, running Ubuntu? Or is Ubuntu your physical host?

Comment: Hi @VonC, I'm in a VM already , running ubuntu. Physical host is a windows machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm in a VM already , running ubuntu. Physical host is a windows machine

Then you don't need docker-machine.

You would create a small Linux image from windows with (again, type in a regular Windows CMD shell)

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox dev
```

But on a full-fledged Ubuntu VM, you just need to [install docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/) and run it directly.

If you need to use docker-machine, just copy (on Windows) [`v0.6.0-rc1/docker-machine_windows-amd64.exe`](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.6.0-rc1/docker-machine_windows-amd64.exe) as docker-machine.exe anywhere you want.
Also: `set VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\` (if your VirtualBox is installed there)

You now can use `docker-machine -d virtualbox dev`.

> 2) Will the ubuntu box, be able to do the docker-compose and build the container on that host?

Yes, no issue there. [The installation is straightforward](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).

> 3) If I'm pulling an image like debian, how can I use it as a machine and build an container on top of it?

You simply write a `Dockerfile` starting with `FROM debian:jessie` (see [an example here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example)), add some commands (`RUN`, `COPY`, ...): for instance:

```
FROM debian:stable
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --force-yes apache2
EXPOSE 80 443
VOLUME ["/var/www", "/var/log/apache2", "/etc/apache2"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Build it (`docker build .`)and run it (`docker run`).

Comment: Thanks @VonC . Reading your answer, I have two questions : 1) How should I make the virtualbox and the docker config see that new "virtualbox"? 2) Will the ubuntu box, be able to do the `docker-compose` and build the container on that host? 3) If I'm pulling an image like debian, how can I use it as a machine and build an container on top of it? 

The tutorial worked fine on standalone linux machine but on virtualbox, it is feels tougher ...

Many many thanks for your answer(s)

Comment: And did I say two? I meant three but I wrote 2. Sorry. Thanks @VonC

Comment: @AndyK see the example: some directives in the Dockerfile: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example

Comment: Many many thanks @VonC , dealing with docker in that way helps me to get the logic (can I use the word logic here?) of docker.

Comment: @AndyK No problem: it is a bit convoluted indeed on Windows, where the VirtualBox introduces an addition level of indirection (as illustrated in https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/#learn-the-key-concepts-before-installing)

Comment: I'm in a similar situation: I have Ubunut running in VirtualBox (with VT-X/AMD-v enabled) on my Windows machine. I have docker installed on Ubuntu and want to follow the Docker tutorial within the Ubuntu VM without touching my Windows machine. I'm stuck at [part 4](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#create-a-cluster) as I get the same error (VT-X/AMD-v not enabled) when trying to run `docker-machine create` within the Ubuntu VM. Is it not possible to use Docker and finish the tutorial completely inside the VM?

Comment: @CGFoX It is best to ask a new question (unless this is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/34855068/6309)

Answer (score 6):

If you do not want to change the BIOS settings, please run the below command.
I have the same problem because I have Hyper-V manager installed in my Windows 8 server. To avoid this issue I ran the below with the below option

```
--virtualbox-no-vtx-check
Example: docker-machine create default --virtualbox-no-vtx-check
```